# Failed to bind to port

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

So I want to start a small Minecraft server to raise money toward a bigger one, so I download a Spigot server (and I have owned some servers in the past so I knew how to set it up). When I finish setting up port forwarding and all that crap, then when I start it up it says this:

```
**** FAILED TO BIND PORT!
```

So I went online to find how to fix it and I was met with a number of different methods. I tried changing the port, changing the IP, using the cmd, using task manager, closing Java, and then started it back up. I was met with the same message. I tried to fix again, but it still gave me the error.

[image: What I see]

Comment: No that didn't help. The ip feild is filled and the other tasks running on the same port are closed. Thanks tho

Comment: Showing your IP is not wise. You should be careful to censor it in the future.

Comment: Yes thank you. I caught that right after i posted it. And i could not figure out how to change it. thank you for doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your server in your private (home) network, be sure that the server IP is the local IP of your computer/server in your network not the one who is accessible from public.

You can check if your current IP is a local one:

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```

If your current IP in server.properties is included in above ranges, there you go.

As Aidan Mueller mentionend, left it blank will automatically take your local IP.

Comment: Yes! Thank you that worked! One more question. Where do i find the ip to share it w/ friends when i leave it blank? Is it the ipv4 address?

Comment: If i type in the ipv4 nothing comes up except: **_java.net.ConnectExeption: connection timed out: No further information_**

Answer (score 0):

**IP** 
I'm not sure if you ever need to fill the IP field. I have always left it blank, so try that first.

**Port** 
A [BindException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html) is usually caused by a port being in use. It looks like another program may be using that port. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) has information on checking for open ports. That should help you find an open port. One answer says that this command will show you ports that are in use:

```
netstat -a -b
```

Comment: It said The requested operation requires elevation. What does that mean?

Comment: @CanColsto You need to move the computer a bit higher for it to work. Put some books under it :P. OK, seriously. It means that the command needs to be run as administrator. Start the command prompt as administrator first.

Comment: thaink you. And for the record. I do have books under my pc tower XD

Comment: @CanColsto If my answer fixed the problem, don't forget to accept.

Comment: Ok i went through a few times but i dont see anything that has _**25565**_ on it. What now?